# how to move items from available section of palette to selected section based on the item selected in the dropdown of same form?

Tags: java, wicket

In Wicket, I have created a form containing one drop down and palette of same data type. If I want to move items from available section to selected based on the value selected in the drop down. How to do that?

Comment: Could you share what you have done so for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways to do this: either client-side with javascript or server side with ajax.

If you were to do it with Ajax, you could use an [`AjaxEventBehavior`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxEventBehavior.html) to detect that there was a change in the dropdown. Then change the model of the palette's selection to whichever items you'd like to be selected. Then re-render the palette by adding it to the `AjaxRequestTarget` given to you by the [`AjaxEventBehavior#onEvent`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxEventBehavior.html#onEvent(org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget)). This would have a slight latency compared to the javascript solution, but it would be cleaner, as it would use Palette the way it was meant to be used (in a sense). I feel like it could make your life easier down the line.

If you were to do this via javascript, you could bind an onchange event listener to your dropdown, which would move the options from one side to another. The palette works by using two `<select>` components for the display and a single `<input type="hidden"/>` for passing the selection back to wicket. In order to do what you ask via javascript you would have to move the `<option>` components from one `<select>` representing unselected components to the other, and then modifying the value of the hidden input to contain/no longer contain the ID value of the selection.
This solution is a bit more dirty in my opinion, but it would probably reap you the best performance.

Comment: Working amazingly well! Thanks :)